# How do we instantiate query in Lucene 5

Tags: java, search, lucene

The old way seems to have been, for example,

```
Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
```

What is the new way? In my case I have search string `"Love in air". My index has multiple documents of course and the documents have multiple fields such as title, description, and a bunch of reviews. I want to search against all the fields. How do I do that in version 5 of lucene?

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.*
```

Seems to be missing in lucene 5. I cannot find

```
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
```

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser` is still there.  If the class isn't being found, the issue is likely with your classpath.  Remember, the queryparser is in `lucene-queryparser-5.0.0.jar`, not `lucene-core-5.0.0.jar`, so make sure you've got them both in your classpath.

As far as the changes in the `QueryParser` signature, passing in a `Version` argument was deprecated in 4.10, and has been removed in 5.0.0.  Just remove the version argument.

```
Query q = new QueryParser("title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
```